# Netstat shows port 80 listened, however nmap gives different result

Tags: curl, nginx

I configured Nginx reverse proxy for my website, and attempt to redirect all requests from port 80 to port 443. At first, I thought my configuration for redirecting from http to https worked fine since I tested by typing http://example.com in both Firefox and Chrome which all redirect the requests to https://example.com. However, few of my friends told me the redirection fails for them. Thus I tested the same thing again by curl which gives me the result:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 80: Connection refused
```

I then performed netstat in my machine which I obtained the following result.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13257/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      13257/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13257/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      13257/nginx -g daem
```

From the result, it seems like nginx is listening to port 80. Nevertheless, when I perform nmap to my machine. The result nmap returned seems like port 80 is closed somehow.

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp open   https
```

This is my nginx conf file.

```
server{
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com;
...
```

I really have no idea why port 80 is closed so any help will be much appreciated !

Comment: Is your firewall correctly configured?

Comment: @mageos sudo ufw status gives me inactive